# Apply a .less in TYPO3 with the bootstrap_package

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, typo3

I got the site running with the default looks, but obviously I also want a little bit of customization.
So I hopped right away on http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/ to create a custom design.

For the sake of simplicity, I just replaced the `EXT:bootstrap_package/.../Theme/variables.less` and `.../Bootstrap/variables.less` file with the one I got from the website, unfortunately without any effect. Literally nothing changed.

Already cleared the cache in the install tool.

Comment: You should avoid changing in extensions you loaded from TER. If any security update is available, you are in trouble. Create an own site_package, and extend bootsrap_package for your needs, as Benjamin Kott recommended. https://speakerdeck.com/benjaminkott/the-anatomy-of-typo3-sitepackages http://sitepackagebuilder.com/

Comment: @jokumer Thanks, I know. But I first want to get that running and once everything works I'll copy the files over to my other extension. Do you have any help for my actual problem?

Comment: Okay, sorry. Dont have experience with .less, cant help in this case

Comment: I think my .less gets overwritten by the constants... Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom variables.less are not used to transpiling the Less-file because
the extension offers the possibility to set the bootstrap Less variables in the constant editor and this is activited by default with the TypoScriot constant
**plugin.bootstrap_package.settings.overrideLessVariables**.
To avoid this default behavior, you have to set the constant to 0.

But as already mentioned in the comments it is not a good idea to change the file directly in the extension. The extension offers the possibility to set the bootstrap Less variables in the constant editor. Select the category **BOOTSTRAP PACKAGE: STYLING** and there you can overwrite the variables.

[bootstrap_package TypoScript constants for bootstrap LESS variables](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/Bootstrap/constants.txt)

Comment: Used the constants as well because I'm impatient, but the `overrideLessVariables` seems like the best solution for applying `variables.less` quickly. Thanks!